# window.onload no funciona cuando la pagina se inicia desde el cache

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando usar un loader con el evento `window.load` y todo me funciona muy bien. Pero al parecer en chrome, no se el resto de navegadores,
cuando la pagina se carga desde el cache no se dispara el `onload` evento.

Al parecer pasa lo mismo cuando se usa onload con una imagen. Solo que con imagenes la solucion a esto es establecer el src atributo despues de agregar el handler al evento.

Pero con `window.load` no se como podria solucionar ese problema.

Dejo aqui el codigo del loader que estoy usando:

```
    window.onload = function(){
        if(containerLoader){
            containerLoader.fadeOut(200);
        }
        if(loaderMap){
            loaderMap.fadeOut(200);
        }        
    }
```

Como dije me funciona muy bien un par de veces pero si actualizo varias veces comienza a quedarse cargando el loader. Ademas estoy trabajando con shopify el cual me parece tiene incluido metodos para cachear la pagina y cargar mas rapido.

Comment: ¿Has probado [readystatechange como alternativa al evento load](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState#readystatechange_como_alternativa_al_evento_load). Aplicado a tu contexto sería así: `document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (document.readyState == "complete") {
    if(containerLoader){
            containerLoader.fadeOut(200);
        }
        if(loaderMap){
            loaderMap.fadeOut(200);
        }
  }
}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

el evento onload no funciona bien por los problemas de caché que se ha comentado con anterioridad.
Puedes probar

```
window.onpageshow = function () {
//algo
};
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onpageshow.asp

Comment: Guao perfecto busque mucho y no logre encontrar la solución. No conocía para nada ese evento. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Por lo que veo es un error bastante frecuente de algunos navegadores, por lo que he visto, incluyendo el CDN de jquery en tu sitio debería funcionar.

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.js"
  integrity="sha256-HwWONEZrpuoh951cQD1ov2HUK5zA5DwJ1DNUXaM6FsY="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

Parece ser que los desarrolladores de Chrome aún no han corregido este problema.

Comment: Estoy usando Jquey y no funciona

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con [readystatechange como alternativa al evento load](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState#readystatechange_como_alternativa_al_evento_load).

[Según la doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState#valores) esto debería funcionar, porque el estado `complete` ocurre cuando:

> El documento y todos los sub-recursos han cargado completamente. El
> estado indica que el evento [`load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event) ha sido disparado.
>
> Cuando el valor de esta propiedad cambia, un evento
> [`readystatechange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readystatechange_event) (en-US) se dispara en el objecto
> [`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document).

Aplicado a tu contexto sería así:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (document.readyState == "complete") {
    if(containerLoader){
            containerLoader.fadeOut(200);
        }
        if(loaderMap){
            loaderMap.fadeOut(200);
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: De hecho esto tampoco resuelve el problema. Y es que si no se dispara onload tampoco ese evento.

Answer (score 1):

el evento load tiene reportados varios problemas al cargar desde el caché.
Puedes usar onpageshow en su defecto.

```
window.onpageshow = function () {
  //bla bla bla
};
```

Esto podría resolver el inconveniente, pero tiene sus limitaciones con versiones anteriores a IE 11 o Safari 5.

https://caniuse.com/?search=pageshow

[Aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pageshow_event) puedes ver la documentación del evento.